# how to create api proxy for favicon.ico in AWS API gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway

so - in API gateway - create the following:

- resource: favicon.ico
- method: GET as http proxy to my icon on another icon on my domain
- integration request:  type http, input passthrough: yes
- integration response - Content-Type mapping value 'image/png', no mapping template defined
- method-response - Content-Type maps through

If I test it, it seems to be returning binary output starting with PNG - but if I go there from a URL, I get the correct content-type - but the image is not valid - it's turning up as an empty square.  When I look at the network tab in chrome, it sees it as image/png.

One difference is the content-length, which is 3114 in the original, but 2470 when I go through the proxy - because it's coming out gzipped - but a) don't know if that's the problem and b) don't know how to stop the API gzipping it.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?